# Saving data to database from new form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a program that uses a dataGridView on Form1 to display data from a SQL Server database.

The user can also edit and save data back to the DB from the Form1 dataGridView.

However, I also have a search function that will pop up a new form and display the results of the search.

I want users to be able to save directly from the new window but at the moment it is only updating the data in the Form1 dataGridView.

This is what I am using to display the results of the Search.

```
private void ResultsFunc()
    {
        var ColumnToSearch = comboBox1.Text;

        if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            var toSearchBy = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            aSH_ORDER_DBDataSet1.ASH_PROD_ORDERS.DefaultView.RowFilter = ColumnToSearch + " = " + "'" + toSearchBy + "'";
        }
        else if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            var toSearchBy = textBox1.Text;
            aSH_ORDER_DBDataSet1.ASH_PROD_ORDERS.DefaultView.RowFilter = ColumnToSearch + " = " + "'" + toSearchBy + "'";
        }

        Form2 resultsForm = new Form2();
        resultsForm.dataGridView2.DataSource = aSH_ORDER_DBDataSet1.ASH_PROD_ORDERS.DefaultView;
        resultsForm.Show();
    }
```

This is what I am using to try save the data from Form2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aSH_PROD_ORDERSTableAdapter.Update(aSH_ORDER_DBDataSet1);
    }
```

How can I get the info entered in Form2 to save directly to the database rather than just update the dataGridView in Form1?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SqlBulkCopy, it can update data to SQLServer 
but make sure you have the necessary columns and schema in the datatable

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    try  
    {  
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SchoolConnectionString"].ConnectionString;  
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(cs))  
        {  
            DataSet ds = aSH_ORDER_DBDataSet1;  
            DataTable dtStudentMaster = ds.Tables["Student"]; 
            //  ds.Tables["Student"], if aSH_ORDER_DBDataSet1 has multiple tables in it specify the table name else ds.Tables[0] is fine
            sqlConn.Open();  
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlbc = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConn))  
            {  
                sqlbc.DestinationTableName = "StudentMaster"; 
                // StudentMaster - Table need to be updated in SQLServer
                // Make sure you have the similar column names and datatype in both datatable and sql server table
                sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");  
                sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Phone", "Phone");  
                sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Address", "Address");  
                sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Class", "Class");  
                sqlbc.WriteToServer(dtStudentMaster);  
                Response.Write("Bulk data stored successfully");  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    catch (Exception ex)  
    {  
        throw ex;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what i am looking for.